# unsupported driver [https], laravel when deployed to heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku, azure-sql-database

I am trying to deploy a Laravel application to Heroku and connect it with a database which has already been deployed to Azure.
But I am having error "unsupported driver[https]".

My `database.php`:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql'
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL','https://firstsqlaap.scm.azurewebsites.net/phpMyAdmin/db_structure.php?server=1&db=localdb&token=51b0b3471e798a712e129bcd1ebe5b01'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '53082'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'localdb'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass'),
            
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

];
```

My `SESSION_DRIVER` is set to database because when set to file it was saying 419 error. I do not have any migration files as my database is deployed to Azure.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: check your env file for `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),` or replace it with `'default' => 'mysql',`

Comment: in .env i have the ```DB_CONNECTION```=mysql

Comment: In a ```SESSION_DOMAIN``` I have to mention the url of my heroku webapp, right?

Comment: Side note, I don't think having your database deployed on Azure should have any bearing on whether you have migration files or not. I suggest you commit those.

Answer (score 1):

This certainly isn't the right URL to use:

```
https://firstsqlaap.scm.azurewebsites.net/phpMyAdmin/db_structure.php
```

You appear to be pointing to an instance of *phpMyAdmin*. phpMyAdmin isn't a database server, it's a dataase *client*. It's a tool that you might use to interact with your database. You need to provide the URL to your actual *database*.

Your [database URL](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#configuration-using-urls) should look more like this:

```
driver://username:password@host:port/database?options
```

For MySQL, `driver://` is likely `mysql://`.

I don't have any MySQL databases running on Azure, but it looks like a real URL might be something like

```
mysql://user:password@your-database-instance.mysql.database.azure.com/your-database-name
```

Go into the Azure portal and navigate to your database instance. Then, in the left navigation panel, [click on "Connection strings"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-connection-string#get-the-connection-string-details-from-the-azure-portal). The information you need should be there, though not in URL format. You can either build your own URL by plugging the right values in or use the individual settings in your `config/database.php` file.

Answer (score 1):

I commented url and it work for me
[image]

Comment: Thanks!! works for me except I edit part of the code for pgsql as using that db